# TypeScript: Incompatible overload signatures

Tags: typescript

I am overloading a function in TypeScript like this:

```
public fireEvent(eventName: string): void;
public fireEvent<T>(eventName: string, messageDTO: T): void;
public fireEvent<T, D>(eventName: string, messageDTO: T, dataCallback: Callback<void, [D]>): void;
public fireEvent<D>(eventName: string, dataCallback: Callback<void, [D]>): void {
    //
}
```

The mentioned `Callback<void, [D]>` implementation is:

```
type Callback<TReturn = unknown, TArgs extends any[] = []> = (...args: TArgs) => TReturn;
```

But I'm encountering compile time error message:

```
TS2394: This overload signature is not compatible with its implementation signature
```

I can't understand how this is not compatible, as I have declared all possible call signatures.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks :)

Comment: What is `Callback`?  Please make sure your code is a [mre] that demonstrates your problem and does not introduce other problems (like undeclared types).  Also, I cannot reproduce your `string | undefined` IDE thing, so please triple check that this happens when you paste your code into a standalone IDE like [The TS Playground](https://tsplay.dev/w1P7YW)... and that's a separate question, anyway, right?

Comment: Note that for this to be a [mre] all you would need to do is provide a toy example like [this](https://tsplay.dev/w1P7YW).  Maybe you could [edit] your question to use that example instead (as plain text, not just a link)?  In any case the answer is that it is incompatible because it means you can call the function with just one parameter, but the implementation expects multiple.  You would need to make the parameters after the first optional in the implementation in order for it to work.  I could write up an answer explaining once the question is in an improved state.

Comment: Hello there! There were mainly two problems. Overnight I have figured that out. The first problem I was implemented an implementation signature, thanks to you :) . I did some research and solved it

Comment: The second one, that my IDE was not highlighting the types after type checks. Well that was solved after upgrading the TS version from 4.0 to 4.6. I don't know if that was a problem in that TS version or what. But upgradation did solved it.

Comment: Could you please [edit] the question to remove references to the irreproducible secondary problem?

Answer (score 0):

I have added an implementation signature as:

```
public fireEvent(eventName: string): void;
public fireEvent<T>(eventName: string, messageDTO: T): void;
public fireEvent<T, D>(eventName: string, messageDTO: T, dataCallback: Callback<void, [D]>): void;
public fireEvent<D>(eventName: string, dataCallback: Callback<void, [D]>): void;
public fireEvent<T, D>(eventName: string, messageDTO?: T | Callback<void, [D]>, dataCallback?: Callback<void, [D]>): void {
    //
}
```

Basically, all the possible combinations of all overloads

Comment: Could you elaborate on how this solves the problem and why the version in the question doesn't work and linking to source documentation?  I was going to write up an answer here, but since you've already done so using the suggestion I made, it would be nice if the answer here were improved.